# Load a dart script dynamically using dart

Tags: dynamic, dart

I'm trying to load a dart script dynamically using dart. I'm using something like this:

*test.html:*

```
...
<script src="http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
<script type="application/dart" src="test.dart"></script>
...
```

*test.dart:*

```
#import('dart:html');
main() {
    var script = new ScriptElement();
    script.type = 'application/dart';
    script.src = 'helloworld.dart';
    document.body.elements.add(script);
}
```

It doesn't work. However, if I inline the same code in the HTML file, it works fine:

*test.html:*

```
...
<script src="http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
<script type="application/dart">
#import('dart:html');
main() {
    var script = new ScriptElement();
    script.type = 'application/dart';
    script.src = 'helloworld.dart';
    document.body.elements.add(script);
}
</script>
...
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It look like a bug. Maybe you should add a issue on [dartbug](http://www.dartbug.com)

Comment: I agree. Currently Dart should not be loadable through the ScriptElement() (this is to load javascript and even that inter-communication is very much up in the air).
Currently the primary way to load dart code is with Isolate.spawnURI()

Comment: @MattB: I saw it's possible to inline dart code: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/embedding-in-html/ and It works!

Comment: Yes it is possible to embed the dart code. It's just that ScriptElement is not designed to work with Dart code, only JavaScript. And even that is not designed to share access to the code that is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Dart. Here is a link to the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4584).

Comment: Seems isolates are the only supported way of dynamically loading Dart code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in Dartium (as Dart) or in another browser (as JavaScript)? I'm going to assume the latter. If you look at (http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js), it looks for script tags such as foo.dart and automatically loads foo.dart.js. It does this in a window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {...}) callback. That callback happens before your code that dynamically adds a script tag.

Hence, you could load helloworld.dart.js in your code instead, which is what (http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js) would do anyway. Note, however, that Dart, ideally, tries to treat each script tag as a separate isolate--it's not like JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to dynamically load dart code: http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/04/dynamically-load-code-with-dart.html?m=1

Without manipulating the DOM. Using dart:isolates